# From Stata to R: forvalues equivalent

Tags: r, for-loop, stata

I am trying to replicate the following code from Stata to R and I am wondering what are the equivalent functions I need to use in order to create the `forvalues` loop in R.

```
egen MuncodeNum=group(muncode)

forvalues MI=1(1)2457{
    gen Muncode`MI'=(MuncodeNum==`MI')
    gen yearxMuncode`MI'=year*Muncode`MI'
}
```

Thanks so much in advance :)

Comment: Not the question, but this would not be good technique in Stata, You are creating 4914 extra variables (columns in the dataset), half of which are indicator (dummy) variables. and half of which are products of those with another variable. In Stata in practice, factor variable notation would almost always be used instead. Otherwise put, if you explain why you need these variables -- in R, as well as in Stata -- there is likely to be a quite different answer.  I am not at all expert in R, so stop there.

Comment: hi! thanks for replying! I'm replicating a paper, and so the authors create the dummy variables for each municipality to introduce controls and time trends (I think this is the part of the code were they set up for it). Then they multiply the dummy variable times the year, so that variable takes the value of the year i or 0 otherwise.

Comment: Understood, but my comment remains. You don't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, you could do the following:

```
# create sample dataset
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
df <- data.frame(year= rep(2010:2020, each=2000),
                 MuncodeNum=sample(1:2457,22000, replace=T))

# Recreating Stata Local Loop
for (i in c(1:2457)) {
  df[[paste0("Muncode", i)]] <- ifelse(df$MuncodeNum==i, 1, 0)
  df[[paste0("yearxMuncode", i)]] <- df[[paste0("Muncode", i)]]*df$year
}
```

However, Nick's warning is applicable to R as there are more compact syntax options to model fixed effects (the form of which would depend on the model specification, for which I do not know specifics).